# Heroes VI graphical problem in third Necropolis mission

Tags: might-and-magic-heroes-6

In the third Necropolis mission, after I take the first Orc Stronghold, when I see the screen that says what artifacts I have won my graphics card appears to reset (both of my monitors reset) and after that the entire Heroes VI screen is invisible, so I cannot play. This happened exactly the same way again after I reloaded from a save. Can I avoid this and still defeat the Orcs?

This graphical glitch has happened before, but the other times it went away when I reloaded from the save.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I avoided this by moving near the battle, saving again, and then continuing on to fight the battle (without reloading the save or anything). I suspect that the most recent patch (which was released since I asked this) may have fixed whatever problem caused it.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing/lowering your graphic-settings. Maybe this avoids the problem.
Also updating the driver of the graphic-card is never a bad idea.